# AngularJS Material dropdown options not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material, md-select

I'm trying to build a form using AngularJS Material and am having problems getting my dropdown options to show up.  My HTML is below and my options are stored in an object array on my server script.  What am I doing wrong below?

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm ng-switch-when="choice">
    <label for="{{element.section_element_name}}">{{element.section_element_label}}</label>
    <md-select id={ {element.section_element_name}} type="selectbasic" value={{element.q_value}}>
        <md-option ng-repeat="option in element.section_element_choices" value="{{option.element_choice_value}}">
            {{option.element_choice_label}}
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: you cand add an exemple of your element object ?

Comment: first you should add ng-model="selectedItem"  in your md-select tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm ng-switch-when="choice">
  <label for="{{element.section_element_name}}">{{element.section_element_label}}</label>
  <md-select id={ {element.section_element_name}} type="selectbasic" ng-model="selectedItem">
    <md-option ng-repeat="option in element.section_element_choices" value="{{option.element_choice_value}}">
        {{option.element_choice_label}}
    </md-option>
</md-select>
```

Comment: whoa, that worked like a charm!  Sorry, I'm pretty new to angular, where is ng-model="selectedItem" defined?  just trying to understand why that works =).  Thanks!

Comment: ngModel is responsible for Binding the view into the model, which other directives such as input, textarea or select require.

in your case ng-model is required by directive md select.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel